# Can I separate some tables in my SQL DB for backups?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I've got a large database with many tables. Numbers not important.  MSSQL 2017 (14.0.2037.2) on Server 2016 that I have full control of.

A huge amount of my data is in two or three tables. Imagine you were tracking cars, you'd have a table of a few thousand cars and each car has millions of data points after a while. Literally 80% of my storage space is used by three tables.

In production there's no issue. Backups happen, restores test successfully, all is well.

I want to be able to pull the non-stupidly-big tables down to dev occasionally for troubleshooting or simply to get some real world data from the other tables. I don't need the big tables. It takes an hour and has to go through a file transfer service (which would put my database with private data outside of my control).

To simplify the question, is there an easy way to backup only select tables to restore on the dev server? I think I'm about to try moving the big tables to a separate file and just copy the remaining small file but that's not as clean or bulletproof as a proper backup/restore of course.

Advice from any SQL gurus?

**edit - having had this running for some time, the answer below was technically correct but not practically useful in the end. I did have my big tables in their own filegroup which allowed me to backup the files separately, however I couldn't simply take the smaller file and restore it without its big siblings anyway without introducing risk and manual stuffing about.

"Fastest" option was to restore the database on the local server and then truncate the unnecessary tables, then backup and restore that database to dev.

Of course now, I've gone Azure so it's all redundant.

Just go Azure people.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/287591/sql-server-restore-only-primary-filegroup-but-bring-the-database-online) will help. Also, the [import and export wizard](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/start-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15) might be useful since you can chose the tables you want to import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to create a secondary database file (.ndf file) on a new filegroup, and move one or more big table to the new filegroup, and make use of backup/restore filegroups feature.

Once you have created the new database file and filegroup, move the table to the newly created file group as explained in [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5832/move-sql-server-tables-to-different-filegroups/) article.

Below you will find a full demo of using backup/restore of filegroups recovered from [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/213061/how-to-restore-a-file-group-from-file-group-backup).

```
USE [master]
GO

ALTER database [FGRestoreTEST] set offline with ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
DROP DATABASE [FGRestoreTEST]
GO


--Create sample database
CREATE DATABASE [FGRestoreTEST] ON PRIMARY (
    NAME = N'FGRestoreTEST'
    ,FILENAME = N'C:\SQLServer\FGRestoreTEST.mdf'
    ,SIZE = 5120 KB
    ,MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED
    ,FILEGROWTH = 1024 KB
    )
    ,FILEGROUP [secondaryFilegroup] (
    NAME = N'secondaryFilegroup'
    ,FILENAME = N'C:\SQLServer\secondaryFilegroup.ndf'
    ,SIZE = 5120 KB
    ,MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED
    ,FILEGROWTH = 1024 KB
    ) LOG ON (
    NAME = N'FGRestoreTEST_log'
    ,FILENAME = N'C:\SQLServer\FGRestoreTEST_log.ldf'
    ,SIZE = 2048 KB
    ,MAXSIZE = 2048 GB
    ,FILEGROWTH = 10 %
    )
GO


--Insert some test data
use [FGRestoreTEST]
go
create table TestTable (id int) on secondaryFilegroup 
insert into TestTable values(1),(2)

--Backup the secondary filegroup and then backup the transactionlog
USE [master]
GO

BACKUP DATABASE FGRestoreTEST FILEGROUP = 'secondaryFilegroup' TO DISK = N'C:\SQLServer\secondaryFilegroupBackup.bak'
WITH INIT

BACKUP LOG FGRestoreTEST TO DISK = N'C:\SQLServer\tlog.trn'
WITH INIT;

--Restore the secondary filegroup and then restore the transactionlog
--taken in the previous step
use [master]
go
RESTORE DATABASE FGRestoreTEST FILEGROUP = 'secondaryFilegroup'
FROM DISK = N'C:\SQLServer\secondaryFilegroupBackup.bak'
WITH norecovery

RESTORE LOG FGRestoreTEST
FROM DISK = N'C:\SQLServer\tlog.trn'
WITH recovery;

--At this point, you should have seen the messages about 
--Additional roll forward past LSN ... is required to complete the restore sequence
--Take an additional log backup and then restore with recovery
BACKUP LOG FGRestoreTEST TO DISK = N'C:\SQLServer\Taillog.trn'
WITH INIT;

RESTORE LOG FGRestoreTEST
FROM DISK = N'C:\SQLServer\Taillog.trn'
WITH recovery;

--Verify you can select from TestTable
use [FGRestoreTEST]
go

SELECT *
FROM TestTable
```

Comment: Thanks Alberto! Your helpful link and actual code sample is brilliant and I think will add to my overall backup/DR strategy as well as this development-centric task. Marked as answer